# Crear usuario en Laravel 5.3 pasando datos con select

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Estoy creando un formulario de registro en Laravel 5.3, donde uno de los campos es "grupo" que consulta en una base de datos. Los grupos están disponibles y los muestra mediante un `select`. El problema es que no he podido guardar, porque creo no estoy recibiendo el `value` del `select`.

Este es mi codigo del select:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('id_group') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="id_group" class="col-md-4 control-label">Grupos</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="form-control" name="id_group" >
          @foreach($groups as $group)
            <option value="{{$group->id}}">{{$group->name}}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
          @if ($errors->has('id_group'))
              <span class="help-block">
                  <strong>{{ $errors->first('id_group') }}</strong>
              </span>
          @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Esta es la función donde valido los datos del formulario:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:testauths',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'group_id' => 'required|max:255|confirmed',
    ]);
}
```

Esta es mi función `create` donde guardo los datos:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return Testauth::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'group_id' => $data['group_id'],

    ]);
}
```

Al enviar el formulario apesar de tener seleccionado el valor del select, el metodo de validacion me dice que no se ha seleccionado nada.

[image: Error]

Al hacer un dd($data) de la función validate se muestra que el campo "Grupo" se manda vació.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿La validación funciona bien? ¿Los datos están llegando al método `create()` que estás mostrando? ¿No puedes guardar los datos del select o ningún dato del formulario?

Comment: No funciona bien la validación ya que al enviar el formulario no me muestra error al crear sino que simplemente se recarga y no realiza ninguna función.

Comment: Estoy utilizando la validación que usa laravel por defecto para el registro de usuarios, utilice el paquete Hesto/multi-auth que me permite crear el modelo, el controlador, las vistas y el guard para una nueva tabla "user" que en este caso se llama authtest, antes de agregar el campo "Grupo" funcionaba correctamente, solo que no esta recibiendo el value del select y por eso no valida correctamente ese campo obligatorio (Grupo).

Comment: Solo mando el formulario vía post al método register del RegisterController y pues el hace las acciones que por defecto ya vienen implementadas, discúlpame si no he sido claro.

Comment: Corregi un error que habia en un id y ahora si valida el campo, pero sigue sin reconocer la opción seleccionada, captura: http://oi66.tinypic.com/28qyump.jpg

Comment: Si ese fue el error corregido, ahora si valida pero sigue sin tomar el value del select (Post editado con el error).

Comment: ¿Para qué tienes la validación `confirmed` para ese campo? Sería bueno ver un `dd($data);` en el método `validator()`

Comment: Porque ese campo es una clave foranea, necesito que siempre tenga un grupo asociado, edito el post para mostrar el dd($data)

Comment: La verdad no entiendo que tiene que ver que sea una clave foránea con un campo que requiera confirmación (un campo adicional). Tengo formularios muy complejos con bastantes claves foráneas y jamás he necesitado `confirmed` para dichos campos.

Comment: Tienes razón, le quite el [confirmed] y postie el dd($data).

Comment: Pareciera que no hay ninguna selección realizada o que no contienen nada los atributos `value` de cada `<option>`. ¿Podrías verificar el código  HTML generado?

Comment: ESTAS ENVIANDO "id_group" y en tu validacion pides "group_id"

Comment: <select class="form-control" name="id_group" > deberia ser `name="group_id"`

Comment: @MiguelOsorio si te fijas en los comentarios anteriores, dicho error ya fue corregido.

Comment: Efectivamente era eso @Shaz en la consulta solo traía el nombre del curso y no asi el id, por ende se enviaba en blanco esa parte, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de intercambiar información en los comentarios se encontraron y corrigieron tres errores:

1. El atributo `name` del campo enviado no coincidía con el nombre del campo en la validación (uno era group_id y el otro era id_group.
2. Había una validación `confirmed` innecesaria en dicho campo.
3. La consulta no estaba trayendo el Id, por lo cual el atributo `value` en cada `<option>` estaba vacío y esto se veía reflejado en los datos del Request.

Answer (score 2):

EL option está enviando id_group y lo que tu controlador espera es group_id

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('group_id') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
<label for="id_group" class="col-md-4 control-label">Grupos</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <select class="form-control" name="id_group" >
      @foreach($groups as $group)
        <option value="{{$group->id}}">{{$group->name}}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
      @if ($errors->has('id_group'))
          <span class="help-block">
              <strong>{{ $errors->first('group_id') }}</strong>
          </span>
      @endif
</div>
```

Aprovechando: Me parece bien que uses HTML para el select y no blade
pero como haces el update con el valor correspondiente al registro?